# Multithreading vs creating a child process

Tags: multithreading, fork, child-process

How does a browser handle creation of new tabs. Does it fork or create a new thread? Can you point me how I choose between creating a new thread and a child process.

Answer (score 0):

Some modern browser these days create separate processes for new tabs. The reason is that if some site (tab) contains malicious code and is for example frozen the rest of the browsed sites can be still seen.

If you used for example Chrome and you would be on Windows, you could try to kill some chrome.exe processes and you will see only one tab will die. However, in case of chrome it is not completely 1 to 1 (tabs to processes). Some processes are vital for running the browser as is (if you kill them the whole browser will die), so be aware of that if you are gonna to try. :)

Note that almost all browser now have separate processes for plugins (3rd party plugins written e.g. using Netscape API). The reason is the same as with tabs (and is even more understandable).

To find answer for your second question, look for example here:
http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2010/01/for.html